# text instead of icons on TbButtonColumn using Yii-Booster

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I'm using TbButtonColumn to render some icon buttons. I want to render text instead of the icons. Is this possible and how would I alter the following code to do this?

```
        $gridColumns = array(
        array('name'=>'nick_name', 'header'=>'Interests Sets'),
        array(
            'htmlOptions' => array('nowrap'=>'nowrap'),
            'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
            'template'=>'{add} {view}',
            'buttons'=>array(           
                'add' => array
                (
                    'label'=>'See this friend\'s list',
                    'icon'=>'plus',
                    'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("itemList/viewlist", array("friend_id"=>$data->id))',
                    'options'=>array(
                        'class'=>'btn btn-small',
                    ),
                ),
                'view' => array(
                    'label'=>'Search under this friend\'s interesrs',
                    'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("friend/filter", array("friend_id"=>$data->id))',
                        'options'=>array(
                        'class'=>'btn btn-small',
                        ),
                ), 

            ),
        )
    );
```

Comment: Have you even tried **anything**? Most possible and abvious - just leave empty `icon` and `imageUrl`... If in doubt, as master Yoda said, [*use the source*](https://github.com/clevertech/YiiBooster/blob/master/src/widgets/TbButtonColumn.php)

Comment: I've tried a couple of things, but nothing seems close to working. I heed your advice though, I should have looked at the source in more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know nothing about yii-booster, but if it's anything like Yii's CButtonColumn, you only need to set the imageUrl to false. Like this:

```
'view' => array(
    'imageUrl'=>false,  // Setting an empty string does not work in vanilla Yii.
    'label'=>'Search under this friend\'s interesrs',
    'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("friend/filter", array("friend_id"=>$data->id))',
        'options'=>array(
            'class'=>'btn btn-small',
        ),
),
```

Comment: Apologies for not getting around to this sooner, but I've just managed to get this to work and your suggestion of setting imageURL to false did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$gridColumns = array(
    ...
        'buttons'=>array(           
            'add' => array
            (
                'label'=>'text instead of the icons' . 'See this friend\'s list',                    
                'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("itemList/viewlist", array("friend_id"=>$data->id))',
                'options'=>array(
                    'class'=>'btn btn-small',
                ),
            ),

        ),
    )
);
```

if you set 'icon'=>'ololo', run this code:

```
if (isset($this->icon))
    {
        if (strpos($this->icon, 'icon') === false)
            $this->icon = 'icon-'.implode(' icon-', explode(' ', $this->icon));

        $this->label = '<i class="'.$this->icon.'"></i> '.$this->label;
    }
```